# Sitemap not in XML format in Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa, sitemap

We are using Sitecore 9.0.2 and developed all the components using SXA 1.7.1. However Sitemap generated is not in XML format. All the URL's for site are clubbed together. Anybody has an idea how to generate the Sitemap in XML format?

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot or at least more details how the output looks like?

Comment: This is how Sitemap looks like as you can see it's all clubbed together                                                                                                                       https://domainname/en/ https://domainname/en/search https://domainname/en/news 2019-04-05 https://domainname/contact-us 2019-04-07https://domainname/en/ https://domainname/en/search https://domainname/en/news 2019-04-05 https://domainname/contact-us 2019-04-07 https://domainname/en/ https://domainname/en/search https://domainname/en/news 2019-04-05 https://domainname/contact-us 2019-04-07

Comment: @AlivorTikos Instead of putting hardly readable links please update your question with them so that they could be nicely formatted.

Comment: I think it is working alright just check the response in page source view (browser shortcut key `ctrl+u`)

Comment: We want this XML to be rendered on Browser